# Factoring web services?

Tags: wsdl

What are some guidelines for factoring of web services?  On one extreme you have different procedures for every operation, and expose all types through WSDL.  This seems to result in the WS interface changing as often as the business logic.  On the other, a generic interface where the types and validation are performed a layer down from the WS interface.  This second option seems to provide more interface stability, and other possibilities such as service chaining.  I've flip-flopped between the two on multiple projects, and wanted some feedback on how others have approached this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a clear-cut answer here.  What is your business process like?  What would express the semantics of your domain in the best way?

Additionally, you need to take into consideration issues of chatty vs. chunky interfaces.  Are you running on a LAN?  Over the Internet?